# Flutter two Listview in Row

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, mobile

I have 2 listview row widgets inside and I put them inside a SingleChildScrollView so that both have the same scroll. But nothing is visible.

Here is the code:

```
child: Row(children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _scrollController2,
                      children: your_history.map((item) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Sizning javobingiz:"),
                                      Text(item)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      children: true_history.map((item) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [Text("To'g'ri javob:"), Text(item)],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            
          ]),
```

SingleChildScrollView ning ichiga joyladim. Ammo hech narsa ko'rinmayabdi.
only String lists are used

the error is as follows:

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#fb2be relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `Row` and `SingleChildScrollView` and it will start working.
You don't need a `SingleChildScrollView` to make the list scrollable cause the ListView is scrollable itself.

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController2,
              children: your_history.map((item) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text("Sizning javobingiz:"),
                              Text(item)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController,
              children: true_history.map((item) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [Text("To'g'ri javob:"), Text(item)],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List your_history = ['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4'];
    List true_history = ['1','2','3','4'];
    
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      primary: false,
   shrinkWrap: true,
                      
//                       controller: _scrollController2,
                      children: your_history.map((item) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child:Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Sizning javobingiz:"),
                                      Text(item)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      primary: false,
   shrinkWrap: true,
//                       controller: _scrollController,
                      children: true_history.map((item) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [Text("To'g'ri javob:"), Text(item)],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
      );
```